# How to get datepicker working with ag-grid-react in full row edit mode

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to get a datepicker (any datepicker) working with Ag-Grid React.

Things I've tried:

When I copy the sample cell editor datepicker (using jQuery UI datepicker), the error message is the "$" is not defined. When I change that to "window.$", I see a text field where the date column is, but no datepicker.

I tried putting react-datepicker into its own component and referring to that in { component: {datepicker: 'customDatePicker'}}, but that doesn't work. Is there a React-specific example somewhere out there?

This should be possible, right?

Comment: Hi, Any update on this? I am trying to do the same